# ffmpeg how to end video with a black frame/solid color

Tags: video, ffmpeg, command-line

I'm scaling 2 videos of different sizes and hstack them side by side together.

If the length of the two videos is different and for example the first one is over, then it shows the last frame of that video the whole time. I want it to show nothing / a black frame **until the other video is over**

My code so far:

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[2nd][ref];[ref][2nd]hstack" -vsync 0 output.mp4
```

How could this be achieved? (something with *tpad* or *stop_mode* maybe?)

Here are two sample videos to test with:

[testvid1](https://i.imgur.com/3fsMO8Q.mp4)

[testvid1](https://i.imgur.com/SWVzeaN.mp4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tpad filter to attach a single black frame at the end of each input. This will effectively achieve what you want. However, there will be a single all-black frame at the end. So, after stacking, run the blackframe filter to detect it, and use the metadata filter to remove it (the 'enable' condition is added to avoid removing fade-ins at the start).

`ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -i vid2.mp4 -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[2nd][ref];[2nd]tpad=stop=1:stop_mode=add:color=black[2nd];[ref]tpad=stop=1:stop_mode=add:color=black[ref];[ref][2nd]hstack,blackframe,metadata=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=97:function=less:enable='gt(t\,3)'" -vsync 0 output.mp4`